# Best way to get Sizes of ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My application (Windows standalone, WPF, MVVM) jumps around in size when it switches viewmodel - naturally - but this behaviour is ugly.

What is the best way to get the size of the application to be the size of the biggest VM, even of the not yet active ones (at least the ones that are constructed on startup). Is there a standard way to do this? I should say that I am using Caliburn.Micro, too.

Comment: Not sure I follow you correctly, by "size" do you mean the memory used? Why would you want your application to consume more memory if not needed and why is that ugly to be dynamic based on necessity?

Comment: No, not the memory... The display size!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to Caliburn.Micro and relates to WPF in general. In general I would argue that your application should not size to the content, rather the content should size to the application.

In Caliburn.Micro specifically the best place to set the size is on your ShellView as this is what you should load your ViewModels into. Since the shell is always there you simply need to set the shell size and let the content scale out to fit.

Comment: Ok so far so good... But how do I find out the appropriate size of the shell - I want the application to be just the right size for the 'biggest VM' (and this size is a runtime quantity, i.e., may be different each time I start the app depending on how much data there is...)

Comment: For that you are looking for SizeToContent, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841767/how-do-you-keep-the-wpf-window-sized-to-content-with-an-expander-after-resize